# jQuery - Add to Favourites

Tags: jquery, post, jquery-post, jquery-click-event

I have a loads of reports. Each report as it's own page. When the user is on a page, I want them to be able to add a report to their favourites. I don't mean browser favourites, I mean their favourite reports when they log into the system

Googling this, for obvious reasons, brings back endless tutorials/scripts on how to add to the browser favourites which isn't what I want

I have a button saying "Add to Favourites". When this is clicked, the report should be added. The button should then be removed and replaced with one saying "Remove From Favourite"

I realise ASP/PHP will be needed to do the actual adding/removing but any guidance on how to achieve this would be most helpful.

Would it be something along the lines of

```
$(function() {
  $('.report_add').click(function() {
    this_id= this.attr("id");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'reportid'+this_id+'=&userid=789',
      success: function() { ... },
      error: function(){ ... },
      url: '/url/',
      cache:false
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the aim of this question is, as without any server-side code to call your AJAX is pointless.

Comment: use $(this).attr('id') instead of this.attr('id') to make sure jquery work properly

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I know what to do once the data has been posted to PHP/ASP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this:

```
this_id= this.attr("id");

data: 'reportid'+this_id+'=&userid=789',
```

to this:

```
var this_id= this.id;

data: 'reportid='+this_id+'&userid=789',
```

or:

```
var this_id= $(this).attr("id"); // add a jQuery wrapper

data: 'reportid='+this_id+'&userid=789',
```

---

In your code you have two issues

**1.** you are not picking the id correctly because you applied jQuery's `.attr()` method to a dom node instead of jQuery object. so that has to be either `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')`.

**2.** your data string is not well formed:

```
data: 'reportid'+this_id+'=&userid=789',
//-------------^----------^--------------your '=' sign is at wrong place
```

instead you can send the values like this:

```
 data: 'reportid='+this_id+'&userid=789',
```

or

```
data: {reportid : this_id, userid : 789},
```

---

in your code:

```
$(function() {
   $('.report_add').click(function() {
     var this_id= this.id; // <---------update this
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {reportid : this_id, userid : 789}, // <---- and this
        success: function() { ... },
        error: function(){ ... },
        url: '/url/',
        cache:false
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: @C-link i think yes it may create issues as seems to be a gloabal var.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function() {
  $('.report_add').click(function() {
    this_id= $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'reportid'+this_id+'&userid=789',
      success: function() {
      $(this).text('Remove From Favourite');
      },
      error: function(){ ... },
      url: '/url/',
      cache:false
    });
  });
});
```